# Direct Sums of Abelian Groups/$R$-Modules

Tags: modules, group-isomorphism, direct-sum

I have the following problem that I am trying to figure out.

> Let $(A_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a family of abelian groups and let $(B_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a collection such that $B_{i}$ is a subgroup of $A_{i}$ for each $i\in I$. Show that $\bigoplus_{i\in I}B_{i}$ is a subgroup of $\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_{i}$ and that there exists an isomorphism of abelian groups such that $$\frac{\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_{i}}{\bigoplus_{i\in I}B_{i}}\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}\frac{A_{i}}{B_{i}}.$$ Moreover, show that if all of the groups in consideration are $R$-modules over some ring $R$, then the isomorphism above is also one of $R$-modules.

I know that the direct sum is defined as $$\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_{I}=\left\lbrace (x_{i})_{i\in I}\::\:|\{i\in I\::\:x_{i}\neq 0\}|<\infty\right\rbrace.$$ I am having some difficulty showing that $\bigoplus_{i\in I}B_{i}\leq \bigoplus_{i\in I}A_{i}$. I'm assuming that for the isomorphism part, I want to use the natural projection $$\pi:\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_{i}\to\bigoplus_{i\in I}\frac{A_{i}}{B_{i}}, \hspace{2cm} \sum_{i\in I}a_{i}\longmapsto\sum_{i\in I}(a_{i}+B_{i})$$ and then use the first isomorphism theorem. Does this approach sound reasonable? Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

Comment: What exactly is your problem in showing that $\bigoplus B_i$ is a submodule of $\bigoplus A_i$?

Comment: I'm not really sure what I need to do to prove it. Is it something like a subgroup test?

Comment: Well, what does it mean for something to be a submodule of something?

Comment: If $M$ is a module, then $N$ is a submodule if $r\cdot x\in N$ for all $r\in R$ and all $x\in N$ (so $RN\subseteq N$), right?

Comment: ($N$ also needs to be a subset of $M$, and be closed under sums)

Comment: Then you *do* know what you need to prove.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to see it. So if we are given a ring $R$ with two families of modules $(A_{i})$ and $(B_{i})$ with $B_{i}\leq A_{i}$ for all $i\in I$, I need to show that $R(\bigoplus B_{i})\subset \bigoplus B_{i}$?

Comment: If that is what being a submodule means, yes. And you told me it does (you have to also show that $\bigoplus B_i$ is a subset of $\bigoplus A_i$, and that $\bigoplus B_i$ is closed under sums, as I have already told you…)

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: In general, if you want to show that X has property P and property P means that conditions A, B and C hold, then what you have to show is that conditions A, B and C hold.